# Activity not getting launched from broadcast receiver in Android 4.3 Jellybean

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a BroadcastReceiver which is supposed to start an activity on receive of sms. But though the BroadcastReceiver is calling `startActivity()` with proper data, activity is not getting launched if I minimize the app and I am in homescreen.

I have used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` separately.

Below is my code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
                    msgIntent.putExtra("dataString", "my data");
                    msgIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    context.startActivity(msgIntent);

}
```

This problem is only occurring in Jelly bean. In higher version the issue is not observed.
If I am at homescreen MyActivity.java is not launching.

Comment: In Jellybean and prior versions, it was possible to abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast before all apps could get it. Are you sure your `BroadcastReceiver` is getting it? Have you debugged on that version? Is there another SMS app installed that could be aborting it?

Comment: please share some code to understand.

Comment: I have editted the question and added the code. I am getting the Broadcast and the desired data. Only problem is it is not launching MyActivity.

Comment: Debug your code see if its reaching `onReceive()` ??

Comment: Yes I debugged the code and onReceive() is being called. As I mentioned only problem is it is not launching MyActivity. I have seen this issue on Xperia C and Samsung Galaxy S3. Both are version 4.3.

Comment: Also, you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when starting an `Activity` from a non-activity context.

Comment: I didn't mention new task but it is working perfectly in the higher versions. My intention is to redorder to front. Not to create new task